# Simple-JNDI VS SimpleNamingContextBuilder with EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder and already existing Data Source

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-test

Does anyone knows to configure a EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder Datasource with Simple-JNDI?
I have a DataSource for testing purposes that I am building like this:

```
    public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabase datasource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(HSQL)
            .setSeparator(";")
            .addScript("classpath:/tables-definitions.sql")
            .build();
    return datasource;
}
```

And I want to bind this to a JNDI name with Simple-JNDI. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer how to use Simple-JNDI to bind to a jndi name a data source that you already have, in general for testing purposes.

Just an observation if you try to use SimpleNamingContextBuilder:

- SimpleNamingContextBuilder is deprecated in spring 5.2 and above in favour of Simple-JNDI
- Unfortunately  I did not find a great source of documentation for Simple-JNDI which make things for more advanced stuff a bit cumbersome.
- Also SimpleNamingContextBuilder does not work with JTA only with JPA - it does not cover all the naming needs for JTA

Now, how to bind a JNDI name with Simple-JNDI to a data source:

- you need to set Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY to the factory class that you want to do the job for you, in my case I choose org.osjava.sj.memory.MemoryContextFactory - if you look into the location of this class in Simple-JNDI library, you will find more options there, depending of your needs

  ```
  System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.osjava.sj.memory.MemoryContextFactory");
  ```

Then you create a Hashtable and add all the properties you need to set as you set them through properties.

```
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put("org.osjava.sj.jndi.shared", "true");
```

Then you bind the DS to JNDI name as you would do it in old plain way:

- create the initial context with the properties from the Hashtable
- create the sub-context
- then bind the data source to JNDI name/context:

  ```
  InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env);
  ic.createSubcontext("java:/comp/env/jdbc");
  ic.bind("java:/comp/env/jdbc/"+dataSourceJndiname, datasource);
  ```